# How can I combine for loop with list items

Tags: python

I have some names in a list, I want to combine the names with some sentences that I have in a text file.

this is my test.txt, it contains following:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```

This is my code to combine the text file and list item

```
name = ['anjana','ashish','dilip','gaurav','grishma','hira','ishika','manoj',
        'muna']
x=1


with open('test.txt', mode = 'r+', encoding="utf=8") as f:

 for y in name:
  for line in f:
      if line.rstrip():
          line_strip = line.strip()
          tag_strip = '<s> ' + line.strip() +' </s>'
          subject = str(name[0])
          tag_end = ' (' + subject +'_'+ str(x).zfill(2) +')'
          print (tag_strip +tag_end)


          x = x+1
```

with this I can get the desired result for only the first item in the list. it doesn't iterate thru all the items

```
<s> This is line 1 </s> (anjana_01)
<s> This is line 2 </s> (anjana_02)
<s> This is line 3 </s> (anjana_03)
```

what I am looking for is

```
<s> This is line 1 </s> (anjana_01)
<s> This is line 2 </s> (anjana_02)
<s> This is line 3 </s> (anjana_03)
.......... so on until
<s> This is line 1 </s> (muna_01)
<s> This is line 2 </s> (muna_02)
<s> This is line 3 </s> (muna_03)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues. You could go on with using `seek()` method to move cursor to the beginning of the file after each iteration. Secondly, you use only first element from the `name` list instead of using variable `y`. This has most necessary improvments:

```
name = ['anjana','ashish','dilip','gaurav','grishma','hira','ishika','manoj',
        'muna']
x=1


with open('test.txt', mode = 'r+') as f:

 for y in name:
  for line in f:
      if line.rstrip():
          line_strip = line.strip()
          tag_strip = '<s> ' + line.strip() +' </s>'
          subject = str(y)
          tag_end = ' (' + subject +'_'+ str(x).zfill(2) +')'
          print (tag_strip +tag_end)
  f.seek(0, 0)
```

Please, pay attention to proper line formatting. No one uses one space per indentation. Use 4 instead. And more descriptive names like

```
names = ['anjana', 'ashish', ...]
(...)
for name in names:
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I moved  `x=1` below `for y in name:` and added  `x=x+1 ` after  `print (tag_strip +tag_end) ` .Exactly what I needed.  I didn't know anything about **seek**. Will look into it. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

After the file is opened you've iterated through it and `for line in f` doesn't give you any more elements.

Try putting `with open('test.txt', mode = 'r+', encoding="utf=8") as f` after 
`for y in name`

Better still, read your lines in once and add the names afterwards, to reduce the IO component of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following approach:

```
>>> txtdata = """This is line 1
... This is line 2
... This is line 3"""
>>> 
>>> name = ['anjana','ashish','dilip','gaurav','grishma','hira','ishika','manoj','muna']
>>>
>>> result = []
>>> 
>>> for i in name:
...     for idx, data in enumerate(txtdata.splitlines(), 1):
...             result.append('<s> ' + data + ' </s>' + ' (' + i + '_0' + str(idx) + ')')
... 
>>> for i in result:
...     print(i)
... 
<s> This is line 1 </s> (anjana_01)
<s> This is line 2 </s> (anjana_02)
<s> This is line 3 </s> (anjana_03)
...
...
<s> This is line 1 </s> (muna_01)
<s> This is line 2 </s> (muna_02)
<s> This is line 3 </s> (muna_03)
>>>
```

Comment: This answer is correct, though more memory consuming.

Comment: @gonczor, yes you are right since he is just printing it out. whereas i am storing the result in a list and then printing it out, it's a matter of application.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `for line in f` you are *consuming* the data from the file handle.  You should instead *store* the data, and iterate over it multiple times.  You can say `f.readlines()` to get all the lines, then use them in your loop repeatedly.